# How can i display in a archive page a number of post i want

Tags: categories

How can i display in a archive themplate ( post type) page a number of post,

Let say i want to display a number of 20 post....in archive page, under i want to display the pages...

Please look here :

http://cinema.trancelevel.com/trailer/aventuri/page/2/

I use post type pages... all the archive pages are now displayng 12 post..

I want to  be able to display a number...

let say 20 post for trailers - for the trailers category
let say 10 post for actori-  for actori category...

Now i use :

```
<?php is_tag(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `current_post` property in the loop:

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while( have_posts() )
    {
        global $wp_query;
        the_post();

        // Show current post number:
        echo $wp_query->current_post;

    } // endwhile;
} // endif;
```

Comment: @CopilFlavius If it works - please mark it as answer.